# Making Dynamically Created ASP.net Page SEO Friendly

Tags: c#, asp.net, seo

im starting the pseudo code of a new site, and want it to be as SEO friendly as possible.

the site i am creating is a booking agency site with c# and asp.net. essentially bands will register on the site with their availability and other info, and fill out their profile information with images etc. this info will be stored in a db.

creating this is not a problem, but i want the site to be a SEO friendly as possible.

I know google loves huge sites with great content. And all of these profile pages would be an excellent addition to my site for seo purposes. i also hear that google cannot see dynamically generated content when crawling a site.

i want to find a method of coding these pages, so google can see the content when it crawls them.

i need a pointer in the right direction for a solution for this. nothing is off limits - i will basically code my entire site around this principle, i just have no idea where to start looking for a solution. im not looking for a code solution, just what i should be researching to solve this issue.

Thanks in advance

Comment: Your whole question is based on the assumption "I also hear that google cannot see dynamically generated content when crawling a site". You should at least supply where you've heard this and how it applies to your current code. You might be confusing "dynamically generated" with "loaded through (asynchronous) Javascript".

Comment: Guess i got my question slightly wrong. What i really need to know is what methods can i use to programatically create a page when a user creates a profile. Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> i also hear that google cannot see dynamically generated content when crawling a site.

Google can see anything you can retrieve via http GET request (ie: there's a specific URL for it) **and** that someone either linked to or is listed in a published xml site map file.

To make sure that your profile pages fit this, you will want to make sure that profiles are all rendered via a single asp.net *.aspx file that determines which page is shown via a url parameter.  Something that looks like this:

> http://example.com/profiles.aspx?profile=SomeBandName

Now, you probably also want a friendly URL, that looks like this:

> http://example.com/profiles/SomeBandName

To do that, you need to set up [routing](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc668201.aspx).

Comment: ok thanks, in that case i guess my question should what methods should i be researching to programatically create a page when a user fills out a profile?

Answer (score 1):

In order to crawl and index your pages by google or other search engine properly. Follow the following guidelines.

```
i: Page title must be precise and according to content available in page.
ii: Page url should be user friendly.
iii: Content is king (useful content)
iv: No ajax or javascript oriented way to load contents.
v: No flash or other media files. if exist must have description via alt tag.
vi: Create url sitemap of all static and dynamically generated contents.
vii: Submit sitemap to google and keep tracking how google crawl and index your pages. 
fix issues contineously if google found via crawling.
```

In this way your most pages and content will be index properly and fastly.

Comment: You can scratch the sitemap if your site is not huge and all content is discoverable over links. Waste of time, no ranking advantage at all.

Comment: But as for my experience, google crawl and index fastly if you provide sitemap instead of direct links which even i placed on 5 or 6 page rank page. But yes sitemap useful if your site have lots of pages.

Comment: If you make a sitemap you can't spend that time on something else which is more important.

Comment: sitemap for dynamic pages mostly generated via script.

Comment: You need to build that script, though. Need to invest effort.

Answer (score 1):

I'd look into dynamic URL Rewriting.
Basically instead of having one page say http://localhost/Profile.aspx you'll have a bunch of simulated urls like

http://localhost/profiles/Band1

http://localhost/profiles/Band2

http://localhost/profiles/Band3

etc.

All of those will then map to back to the orgial profile.aspx page with a parameter so internally in your code it would look like http://localhost/Profile.aspx?Name=Band1, http://localhost/Profile.aspx?Name=Band2, etc

Basically your website appears to have a bunch of pages for each band but in reality they are all getting mapped back to the same asp.net page but have different parameters.

This is article I read about it some time back.  http://weblogs.asp.net/scottgu/archive/2007/02/26/tip-trick-url-rewriting-with-asp-net.aspx

Answer (score 0):

> i also hear that google cannot see dynamically generated content when crawling a site.

you could create a sitemap.xml with the urls pointing to the dynamic profile pages. using google webmaster tools you can submit and monitor the crawling progress.
you may also create an index page or something similar ('browse by category' pages) that link to matching profile pages.

a reference for seo I regularly use is http://www.seomoz.org/learn-seo